# Using a loop in VBS to rename a file

Tags: file, vbscript, rename

I have a script already which can perform a saveas routine for file names that begin with certain characters.

This is the script below.

```
        'launch Excel and open file
Const xlExcel8          = 56
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
Set fso   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^ABC.*\.xlsx$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\_ThisWeek").Files
  If re.Test(f.Name) Then
    Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open(f.Path)
    xlObj.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlfile.SaveAs "C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\_ThisWeek\Weekly Feed File.xls", xlExcel8

xlFile.Close True


End If
xlObj.DisplayAlerts = True
Next

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^ABC.*\.xlsx$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\_ThisWeek").Files
  If re.Test(f.Name) Then
    fso.Deletefile(f.Path)
End If

Next 


xlObj.Quit
```

Can anyone pls assist with updating the script to rename a file instead of performing a saveas?

Comment: what do you want to rename it to?

Comment: @Deep, anything really, im trying to get my head around starting with a file name that begins with certain chars and then running the script, which will rename it to whatever name i specify. e.g start with anything begins with ABC, and save as XYZ.

Comment: Please copy your whole script above.  It's missing at least the `End If` and `Next` statements but I don't want to assume that is all that was left out.

Comment: @RLH Hi, Pasted the full script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely simple example.

I don't have enough to go on for how you want to rename the file so you need to fill in that logic.  I just defined a variable `strName` that holds a string value for an example.

You would want to set `strName` inside the `If` statement to something that works for you and changes on each loop.

If the path or name will be complex, make sure you double quote the variable.

```
'rename files from one folder to another
option explicit
Dim fso:      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strPath:  strPath = "C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\_AnotherFolder\"
Dim strName:  strName = "SetYourNameHere.xls"
Dim re:       Set re = New RegExp
Dim oFile

re.Pattern = "^ABC.*\.xlsx$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each oFile In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\_ThisWeek").Files
    If re.Test(oFile.Name) Then
        oFile.move strPath
        oFile.name = strName
    End If
Next
```

You already have the file object.  Just move it with it's own method to your other folder then use it's name property to set the value to what you want the name to be.

You should add verification that the file doesn't already exist in the folder and handle that situation gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a file by using the [MoveFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265335(v=vs.60).aspx)

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Fso.MoveFile "Test.txt", "Test2.txt"
```

Comment: i wish to incorporate my loop where it pulls in anything that begins with, rather than using static names.

Comment: then you can try using the [CopyFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127964(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: the copy file method example again has static file names. The loop i have in my save as script takes in any file that begins with certain chars. I wish to retain that but use a rename instead of saveas.

Comment: Deep's example is correct but just showing you static file names.  All you have to do is use variables from your process instead of those static names.  MoveFile supports full path\name for both arguments.

Comment: @RLH Thankyou very much, greatly appreciated! works perfect.

Comment: Ticked the correct answer, if someone wants the entire code let me know. I incorporated RLHs code into mine.